# Set GeoFire value in FireBase tree

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

[image: screenshot of database]

Here's my DB. Whenever I use GeoFire to set a location, I use:

```
geoFire.setLocation("Marker", myLocation);
```

But I haven't figured out how I can get it under a parent. I want to store the values inside of "markerLocation" where it's under a child.

I've tried changing the key in setLocation() to exactly "markerLocation" instead of "Marker" but it still makes its own tree. For the tree, I have:

```
mDatabase.child("User").child("userID").setValue(user1.getId());
```

And I've tried to squeeze in setLocation in setValue but that doesn't work.

How can I set it so that it goes under a parent/child?

Comment: It is recommended to keep the geo-data separate from the other data. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340949/how-to-save-geofire-coordinates-along-with-other-items-in-firebase-database/38341118#38341118

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So it's just better to have the data separate (regular  properties vs.  geohash and keys)?