# How do I get database entries near to a specific location in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

Im working on a locationbased App in Ionic and I am using Firebase as my database. In my App I want to be able to save the location of the user with longitude and latitude.

Everything is working fine so far, but now I want to be able to return specific entries based on the last digits of the coordinates so I get a circle around the location of my user. For example: I'm at the `latitude 50.5000000` and the `longitude 50.0000000`. Now I want to return every entry of my database with the langitude and latitude somwhere between `50.2500000` and `50.7500000` since thats going to be, according to my understanding of longitude and latitude, roughly 50km around my location.

Is there a way to implement such a request or do I have to return every entry and calculate this inside of my App?

Comment: If you're using the Firebase Realtime Database, you're looking for [Geofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272146/firebase-location-query/40272342#40272342). If you're using Cloud Firestore, you're looking for one of the 3rd party [GeoFirestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630507/how-to-run-a-geo-nearby-query-with-firestore) libraries.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)