# GeoFire data has invalid format exception

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am setting up GeoFire for my Android app. At the start of retrieving data from the Firebase database, I am getting the following exception.

> There was an error getting the GeoFire location: DatabaseError: User code called from the Firebase Database runloop threw an exception:
>    W/System.err: java.lang.Throwable: GeoFire data has invalid format: {lon=74.529964, lat=31.4479225}

Apparently, it is retrieving data from the database but still throwing an exception :(

I have used the following code to retrieve data:

```
geoFire.getLocation("test1", new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            if (location != null) {
                System.out.println(String.format("The location for key %s is [%f,%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude));
            } else {
                System.out.println(String.format("There is no location for key %s in GeoFire", key));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.err.println("There was an error getting the GeoFire location: " + databaseError);
        }
    });
```

As I'm new to firebase, is there anything obvious I am missing?[This is how my firebase database looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMrVn.png)

Comment: The error message sounds like the data in the database is considered invalid by GeoFire. Please add to your question how the database was populated.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher i have attached a screenshot of the database structure. I have tried retrieving the data for both test1 and test2. They both give the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GeoFire does not seem to use the keys `lat` and `lon`, or `Latitude` and `Longitude` as you have in your example, but some custom encoding of the location in a property called "g". The correct way to save locations for use by GeoFire seems to be the setLocation method provided by GeoFire.

See [How to save GeoFire coordinates along with other items in Firebase database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340949/how-to-save-geofire-coordinates-along-with-other-items-in-firebase-database/) for a discussion of how the structure in your database should look like.