# Does Firebase "GeoFire" Enforce Identical Keys Between Nodes with Geo and non-Geo Data?

Tags: firebase, geofire

The database structure for a Firebase "GeoFire" node must look like this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38344539/2327328))

```
"items" : {
    <itemId> : {
        "someData" : "someData",
        ...
    }
},
"items_location" : {
    <itemId> : {
        <geofireData> ...
    }
}
```

But one limitation of Geofire is that only single points can be stored and queried, and no objects like polygons. That's easy to work around - my code can query nearby points, and then reassemble the simple rectangles based on having the same key.

But in splitting my rectangles into individual points, I've created a GeoFire key with the following format

```
ABCD_0
```

Where `ABCD` is the original Primary Key of the rectangle, and `_0` indicates which corner, so as to have each point with a unique key. One rectangle is represented in GeoFire as

```
"items" : {
   <ABCD_0> : {<objectData>},
   <ABCD_1> : {<objectData>},
   <ABCD_2> : {<objectData>},
   <ABCD_3> : {<objectData>}
},
"items_location" : {
    <ABCD_0> : {<geofireData 0>},
    <ABCD_1> : {<geofireData 1>},
    <ABCD_2> : {<geofireData 2>},
    <ABCD_3> : {<geofireData 3>}
}
```

But then to force identical keys in `items` and `items_location`, `<objectData>` is 4x redundant.

In order to decrease data volume, I'd like to use the original Primary Key in the `items` node, and then replicate the key with the `_X` structure for the `items_location` node. The App would then query GeoFire, get a list of (4) nearby keys, and then string-parse `ABCD_X` into `ABCD`, which it would use for the subsequent query.

```
"items" : {
   <ABCD> : {<objectData>},
 },
"items_location" : {
    <ABCD_0> : {<geofireData 0>},
    <ABCD_1> : {<geofireData 1>},
    <ABCD_2> : {<geofireData 2>},
    <ABCD_3> : {<geofireData 3>}
}
```

**Will this break how GeoFire stores, indexes, retrieves and offlines data?**

I'm especially concerned about how small sets of data is synchronized offline for individual apps. The entire geo-dataset is too large for a single app to store in its entirety offline.

Comment: GeoFire associates no meaning with the keys that you use to identify items. They can be whatever you want, as long as they fit within the limits that the Firebase Realtime Database has on keys.

Comment: So the answer is No. But the question wasn't so much about naming the keys, but using non-identical keys for `item` and `item_location`, which I thought might negatively affect offline storage