# How to save other properties in the GeoFire.set object, firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, geofire

Currently I have the following node 'Zones' in firebase, which means the zones of the parking lot:
[image]

In this object I must save an object that is called 'parking', that object must contain the properties of lat, long and geohash given by the GeoFire.Set library. I currently keep it in this way separately:
[image]

```
 var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('zona');
  var geoFire = new GeoFire(firebaseRef);
          geoFire.set("some_key9", [37.79, -122.41]).then(function() {
              //console.log("Provided key has been added to GeoFire");
            }, function(error) {
              //console.log("Error: " + error);
            });
```

How can I make the 'zone' node save what I send in geoFire.set newer property so that it looks like this:

```
zona_parqueo1:{
    g: "9q8yyrry8q",
    l:{
      0: 37.79,
      1: -122.41
    },
    parqueos: {
      parqueo1: {
       'nombre': 'parqueo1'
      },
      parqueo2: {
       'nombre': 'parqueo2'
      }
    }
```

Likewise I use the 'on' method to obtain the values ​​and create a marker with latitude and longitude:

```
geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
              //console.log(key + " entered query at " + location + " (" + distance + " km from center)");
              //console.log("LATITUD Y LONGITUD");
              console.log(location);

              let marker = {
                lat: location[0],
                lng: location[1]
              }

             vm.markers.push(marker);

           });
        },
```

Comment: That's not currently possible in Geofire for JavaScript. You'll instead store the properties in a separate top-level node, using the same keys that you use in Geofire. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340949/how-to-save-geofire-coordinates-along-with-other-items-in-firebase-database

Comment: please can you help me by applying it to my code, thank you very much.